# Colorbox IE display inline href function doesn't get triggered second time the the same link clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, colorbox

Hi hope some one can help. Have been trying to display some hidden inline content in a colorbox. Everything works great in firefox but in IE8 it works the first time then fails the second. When using alert(id) the id var is coming up as undefined the second time in IE.

Have tried a click handler to set the id and I get the same result. Here's some sample html (simplified for clarity). This is generated by Drupal CMS

```
<div class="my-div">
    <a class="pop-extra nid-628 cboxElement" href="/alex-f">the link triggering colorbox</a>

    <div id="628" class="inline-content" style="display: none;">
    The hidden content to display
    </div> 
</div>
```

Here's my jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// Hide inline content
$('.inline-content').hide();
//Fire colorbox
$('a.pop-extra').colorbox(
{
height:700,
width:420,
inline:true,
//Set the inline content to display dynamicaly by grabing the next div id
href:
function(){
id = $(this).next().attr("id");
return '#'+id;
},
onOpen:function(){
//Show the content so colorbox has something to display
$('#'+id).show();
},
});

$(document).bind('cbox_closed', function(){
//Hide content again when colorbox closes
    $('#'+id).hide();
});
```

});

To see a demo please have a look at this url:
http://eyestoneartists-com-au.kept.com.au/browse-extras/male/all

To reproduce in IE8 click one of the images, then close the image then click it again.

Comment: I am not finding any issues in the link provided. It works fine for me in IE8.

Comment: It happens the second time the same link is clicked

Answer (score 1):

put the content in another div and then `display:none` in a div before it.